# Dynamically change to bold and italic in listview android

Tags: android

I am developing  a chat application.Here for chat i have used ListView .
I want to set bold and italic options for the text of ListView dynamically. 
setTypeFace is not working for it .
How can i do that?

Comment: Why does `setTypeface` not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTypeFace works. You have to set it in the adapter on the getView() method. For getView to get called you should use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

```
TextView eventText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.eventText);
    if (eventText != null)
    {
        eventText.setText(event.getUserName());
        if (event.isNew()) eventText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        else eventText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

    }
```

Here is an example I used for the setTypeFace() method. This code is in the getView method of the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

First You Create CustomAdapter For listView Like this http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1343 And in textview

```
<TextView android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
```